# should I pass IntPtr by ref for better latency?

Tags: c#, unmanaged

`IntPtr` is a `struct` and so by default is passed by value, this might be expensive (as new object is created every time) and so we better pass it by reference when new object is not mandatory. For example I wrote such code (please ignore hardcoded "magic numbers"):

```
    public static DateTime IntPtrToDateTime(ref IntPtr value, int offset)
    {
        short year = Marshal.ReadInt16(value, offset);
        byte month = Marshal.ReadByte(value, offset + 2);
        byte day = Marshal.ReadByte(value, offset + 3);
        byte hour = Marshal.ReadByte(value, offset + 4);
        byte minute = Marshal.ReadByte(value, offset + 5);
        byte second = Marshal.ReadByte(value, offset + 6);
        short msec = Marshal.ReadInt16(value, offset + 8);
        return new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, msec);
    }
```

Works fine, but I'm doubt if I really should pass IntPtr by reference? I guess `IntPtr` struct is very "light" and likely very easy to create.

Also in `Marshal` class in .NET framework passes `IntPtr` by value, for example [Marshal.ReadInt64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8assa3zs.aspx) I guess `Marshal` class is designed to be the lowest-possible latency, but why `IntPtr` is not passed by reference then?

- What would be faster - pass IntPtr by value or by reference?
- If passing by reference is faster then why `Marshal` class pass `IntPtr` by value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't pass it by reference. That will only cause more overhead in the code in this case.

As it's a structure the size of a pointer, passing it by value and by reference will put the same amount of data on the stack, and it will be about the same amount of work to put it on the stack.

Using a parameter passed by reference will however cause another level of indirection. Instead of reading the value from the stack you will be reading a pointer from the stack and then reading the value using the pointer.

Also, semantially you should only use `ref` or `out` for parameters where you actually want to change the variable used to pass the value.

If you have a large structure that you want to pass by reference for performance reasons, then it's actually the large structure in itself that is causing the performance issues, not how you pass it as a parameter. You should make it a class rather than changing how you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Structs are passed by value and there is no new heap object allocated for them. Also, IntPtr is a type natively understood by the CLR. It is the size of a single pointer. You should expect the same performance profile as you can expect from an `int` or `long` (depending on your bitness).

Passing it by reference will slow things down because you wrap a pointer with a pointer.

Comment: And in the end, a reference to an `IntPtr` would have at least the same length as an `IntPtr` :-)

Comment: in general passing by reference is faster than passing by value because new object don't need to be allocated, why in this case passing by reference would be slower?

Comment: Everything is passed by value... unless explicitly stated otherwise. Reference types are also passed by value.. that is, their reference value is copied to a new reference.

Comment: @javapowered that cannot be said in general. If the reference has the same size as the value referred to it is always slower. Also for relatively small values passing by value can still be faster. Also, a struct is not normally allocated as an object on the heap.